# UITableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths and crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have code like this. When I debug with exception breakpoint, it crash when I `reloadRow`.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return ceil(self.folders.count/ 2);

    else if (section <= self.documents.count) {
        DocumentsCollection *dc = self.documents[section - 1];
        return dc.attachments.count;
    }

    return 0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//..........
[cell setData:dc.attachments[indexPath.row] andReload:^{

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}];
}
```

I am using constraint in my cell and all my data are really correct. I am trying to read error message and find in here too but I don't get it. Please kindly explain how I shall do. I totally don't understand why it say

> "reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'"

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011334fd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011252d21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001132812eb -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 203
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000110c61df6 -[UITableView _existingCellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 159
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000110c8555c -[UITableView _heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 109
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000110ebd783 -[UISectionRowData heightForRow:inSection:canGuess:] + 263
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000110ec5601 -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 1016
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000110ec5707 -[UITableViewRowData rectForGlobalRow:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 142
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000110ec64b9 -[UITableViewRowData globalRowsInRect:canGuess:] + 1101
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000110fa5cf3 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _visibleRowRangePlusAdjoining] + 96
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000110fa5dc8 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _faultInRealHeightsOfNeededCells] + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000110fb81c7 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 164
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000110c544dd -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 3054
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000110c4c90f -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 17960
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000110c63f62 -[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:updateAction:withRowAnimation:] + 331
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000126e4d4a2 -[UITableViewAccessibility reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 73
    16  iFeedback                           0x000000010dc809ad __56-[DocumentVCWithFolder tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 125
    17  iFeedback                           0x000000010dbeb6e8 -[DocumentDetailCell observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 552
    18  Foundation                          0x000000010f25bdec NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 351
    19  Foundation                          0x000000010f25b687 NSKeyValueDidChange + 495
    20  Foundation                          0x000000010f33cb95 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:usingBlock:] + 986
    21  Foundation                          0x000000010f220b01 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 60
    22  Foundation                          0x000000010f2e80df _NSSetSizeValueAndNotify + 285
    23  UIKit                               0x000000011144fa84 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 745
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000111456725 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 313
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000110bd2ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    26  QuartzCore                          0x00000001106e6bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    27  QuartzCore                          0x00000001106da440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000110bc0928 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1509
    29  iFeedback                           0x000000010dbeb4a9 -[DocumentDetailCell setUpTag] + 553
    30  iFeedback                           0x000000010dbeb24a -[DocumentDetailCell setData:andReload:] + 154
    31  iFeedback                           0x000000010dc8078b -[DocumentVCWithFolder tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 1995
    32  UIKit                               0x0000000110c7b584 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 757
    33  UIKit                               0x0000000110c7b7e2 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000110c4f2b0 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295
    35  UIKit                               0x0000000110c84b64 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000110c6b3be -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000110bd2ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    38  QuartzCore                          0x00000001106e6bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    39  QuartzCore                          0x00000001106da440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    40  QuartzCore                          0x00000001106da2be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    41  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110668318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    42  QuartzCore                          0x00000001106953ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    43  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110695d6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001132f4267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001132f41d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001132d8f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    47  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001132d8884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    48  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115340a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    49  UIKit                               0x0000000110b0dc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    50  iFeedback                           0x000000010dc60ebf main + 111
    51  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001138da68d start + 1
)
```

Comment: I thinks it means that you are trying to reload row number 4, but you have only 3 rows in your `UITableView`.

Comment: It is possible but I got indexPath directly from "cellForRowAtIndexPath". Why I have 3 row and I am trying to reload row 4?

Comment: What about `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: I have updated numberOfRowsInSection. It shall be correct too. My break point stop at reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: yes I use dequeueReusableCell too and my cellIdentifier is correct.

Comment: have you tried logging dc.attachments on cell for row?

Comment: yes. I have tried that. In fact, I totally comment out that and I just return 2.  It doesn't crash only when I remove "reloadRow".

Comment: Is there any reason you do `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths ` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath `? I dont think you are doing correctly

Comment: what do you do inside the block though? have you tried calling the reload explicitly on the main thread?

Comment: Inside my block , I just store those action temporarily and do it later. But it is done in main thread also.

Comment: because you specify number of row depend on number of section at  numberOfRowsInSection method so you must specify that also in cellForRow method .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Array` the error is referring to is actually the queue of reusable cells that the `UITableView` maintain. When you call `reloadRowsAtIndexPath`, the `tableView` will ask its delegate for another cell at the same indexPath.

By adding a log into the first and last line of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` my log look something like:

```
 Start for cell at [0, 9]
 Start for cell at [0, 9]
 End for cell at [0, 9]
 End for cell at [0, 9]
 Start for cell at [0, 10]
 Start for cell at [0, 10]
 End for cell at [0, 10]
 End for cell at [0, 10]
 Start for cell at [1, 0]
 Start for cell at [1, 0]
 End for cell at [1, 0]
 End for cell at [1, 0]
 Start for cell at [1, 1]
 2017-01-10 16:48:05.530 TableView[25012:201598] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'
```

which shows that if the completion handler of your `setData` gets called before the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` completes, your `UITableView` will attempt to call for one more cell then it has - note that my error says index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7] and my `UITableView` has got 8 visible cells.

To solve the problem, I suggest not calling `reloadRowAtIndexPath` but instead update the values of whatever display your cell contains directly.

Answer (score 0):

your code is showing error because the block in which you are setting the data might be giving little bit delay. 
The summary of what i meant is that you are reloading the table view from its delegate method. And the reloading is getting called from a block which might be the reason of crash.
You can do one thing, rather then reloading specific row, try to reload whole table.
Hope it will work.

Comment: i had faced this problem when dealing with blocks and table view.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.
Number of Row in every section should equal to objects in Array.
Suppose you pass 4 count in section 1 (which starts at index == 0) should equal to your Array objects.

It is crashing due to ROW count and Object in array is not matching.
If it not matched than you will get

"reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'"**

Bounds [0..3] means Array has only 4 objects and it is trying to get 5th object at index 4.
Please check it and should has proper count in Array object.